# How would I test if a cookie is set using php and if it's not set do nothing

Tags: php, cookies

I've tried

```
 $cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie'];
```

if the cookie is not set it will give me an error

```
PHP ERROR
Undefined index: cookie
```

How would I prevent it from giving me an empty variable>

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) to see if the cookie exists.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])){
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie'];
}
else{
    // Cookie is not set
}
```

Comment: The snippet should promote coding standards, this as is will throw warnings in a few cases.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) for this purpose as follows:

```
$cookie = array_key_exists('cookie', $_COOKIE) ? $_COOKIE['cookie'] : null;
```

Comment: Yay! An anonymous downvote with no explanation - how helpful. :-)

Comment: Nice alternative to the usual isset() approach!

Comment: @JohnParker shouldn't you include if the cookie isset as well since I assume the the point many times is to check if it's not expired ?

Comment: @Mike isset() doesn't do that either. I think array_key_exists() is a much better approach when you know the array - $_COOKIE in this case - exists and is accessible.

Comment: If $_COOKIE['cookie'] exists in $_COOKIE and is NULL, then the function returns TRUE. Do not use it unless you are okay with that!

Check "Example #2 array_key_exists() vs isset()": https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#example-5401

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your needs.

```
// If not set, $cookie = NULL;
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) { $cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie']; }
```

or

```
// If not set, $cookie = '';
$cookie = (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) ? $_COOKIE['cookie'] : '';
```

or

```
// If not set, $cookie = false;
$cookie = (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) ? $_COOKIE['cookie'] : false;
```

References:

- [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
- [ternary operator (?)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Your first one just changes it from an undefined array index to an undefined variable, and you've put the OP back to square one.

Comment: @Marc B, no. It just sets `$cookie` or not. The OP never said he will be using `$cookie` again.

Comment: Yes, and if `$_COOKIE['cookie']` isn't set, then it DOESN'T set `$cookie`, so now you've got an undefined array field AND an undefined variable.. What happens if OP tries to use `$cookie` afterwards?

Comment: Yep, you have them but no errors appear just trying the OP code with my first solution. He asked for the error to disappear. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 $cookie = isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])?$_COOKIE['cookie']:'';
 //checks if there is a cookie, if not then an empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie']??'';
```

Its a shorter form of

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
     $cookie =$_COOKIE['cookie']; //cookie is set
  } else {
     $cookie = ""; //cookie not set
}
```

Then you can do

```
if(!empty($cookie)){
     // do something
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example not mentioned in responses: Say you set a cookie for 60 seconds if conditions are right :

```
if ($some_condition == $met_condition) {
    setcookie('cookie', 'some_value', time()+ 60, "/","", false);
}
```

Technically we need to check that it's set AND it's not expired or it will throw warnings etc.. :

```
$cookie = ''; //or null if you prefer
if (array_key_exists('cookie', $_COOKIE) && isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie'];
}
```

You would want to check in a way that ensures that expired cookies aren't used and it's set, the above example could obviously not always set the cookie etc.. We should always account for that. The array_key_exists is mainly their to keep warnings from showing up in logs but it would work without it.